# JVM to ignore certificate name mismatch

Tags: java, ssl, certificate, truststore

I know there were a lot of questions/answers about how to ignore SSL error in the code.

On our dev region `dev.domain.tld` we have configured a app server over SSL.

The certificate that is displayed is for `somedev.domain.tld`.

There is no way to change the certificate, it will always be a domain mismatch.

So when I deploy a web-service to `https://dev.domain.tld` and try to connect/call my webservice I get an exception:

> Caused by:
>   java.security.cert.CertificateException:
>   No name matching dev.domain.tld found

And I have the `somedev.domain.tld` CERT in my trust store.

Now, I saw a lot of samples how to change that in the code (using a Trust Manager that accepts all domains), but how do I specify to the JVM to ignore the domain mismatch when connecting to the server? Is there a `-Djavax.net.ssl` argument or something?

Thank you!

**UPDATE:**

Or, since I am using Spring-WS, is there a way to set some property in Spring for that? (WebServiceTemplate)

**UPDATE**

I guess I'll have to do use something from Spring Security: http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/sites/1.5/reference/html/security.html

Answer (score 3):

This works for me in a client application of mine, perhaps this will also work for you if you are (or Spring is internally) using HttpsURLConnection anywhere.

```
HostnameVerifier hv = new HostnameVerifier() {
  public boolean verify(String urlHostName, SSLSession session) {
    log.warning(String.format("Warning: URL Host: '%s' does not equal '%s'", urlHostName, session.getPeerHost()));
    return true;
  }
};

HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(hv);
```

Its hardly SSL best practice though. The best solution would be to use a certificate that matches the hostname.

Comment: I think `HostnameVerifier` is the right technique. But, you can still do some better checking, to make sure the mismatch is the one you're expecting (based on knowing the certificate the server is using). Testing against `session.getPeerHost()` I don't think is a good test. I test `urlHostName` against the actual Common Name from the certificate. They may be mismatched, but my HTTP client will test for the **correct** mismatch. See [this question for more](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2914521/119114). SSLSession#getPeerCertificates() can get you started.