# How to extract CN from X509Certificate in Java?

Tags: java, ssl, x509certificate, x509

I am using a `SslServerSocket` and client certificates and want to extract the CN from the SubjectDN from the client's `X509Certificate`.

At the moment I call `cert.getSubjectX500Principal().getName()` but this of course gives me the total formatted DN of the client. For some reason I am just interested in the `CN=theclient` part of the DN. Is there a way to extract this part of the DN without parsing the String myself?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing the CN out of a certificate DN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7933468/parsing-the-cn-out-of-a-certificate-dn)

Comment: @AhmadAbdelghany You realized, that my question is about 1.5 years older than the one linked? So if anything, the other is a duplicate of mine :-)

Comment: Fair point. I will flag the other one.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Here's some code for the new non-deprecated BouncyCastle API.  You'll need both bcmail and bcprov distributions.

```
X509Certificate cert = ...;

X500Name x500name = new JcaX509CertificateHolder(cert).getSubject();
RDN cn = x500name.getRDNs(BCStyle.CN)[0];

return IETFUtils.valueToString(cn.getFirst().getValue());
```

Comment: @grak, I'm interested in how you figured out this solution. Certainly just from looking at the API documentation I was never gonna be able to figure this out.

Comment: yea, I share that sentiment... I had to ask on the mailing list.

Comment: Note that this code on current (Oct 23 2012) BouncyCastle (1.47) also requires bcpkix distribution.

Comment: A certificate can have multiple CNs. Instead of just returning cn.getFirst() you should iterate through all and return a list of CNs.

Comment: Nice find on the `IETFUtils`, that is not obvious at all!

Comment: The `IETFUtils.valueToString` does not appear to produce a correct result. I have a CN that includes some equals signs because of base 64 encoding (e.g. `AAECAwQFBgcICQoLDA0ODw==`). The `valueToString` method adds back slashes to the result. In lieu of that, using `toString` seems to be working. It's difficult to determine that this is in fact a correct usage of the api.

Comment: I think it is better to check `if (0 != x500name.getRDNs(BCStyle.CN).length)`.

Comment: please have a sight at my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40613147/how-to-get-the-policy-identifier-and-the-subject-type-of-basic-constraints-in-a

Answer (score 102):

here is another way. the idea is that the DN you obtain is in rfc2253 format, which is the same as used for LDAP DN. So why not reuse the LDAP API?

```
import javax.naming.ldap.LdapName;
import javax.naming.ldap.Rdn;

String dn = x509cert.getSubjectX500Principal().getName();
LdapName ldapDN = new LdapName(dn);
for(Rdn rdn: ldapDN.getRdns()) {
    System.out.println(rdn.getType() + " -> " + rdn.getValue());
}
```

Comment: One useful shortcut if you're using spring :  LdapUtils.getStringValue(ldapDN, "cn");

Comment: At least for the case I'm working on the CN is *within* a multi-attribute RDN. In other words: the proposed solution doesn't iterate over attributes of the RDN. It should!

Comment: `String commonName = new LdapName(certificate.getSubjectX500Principal().getName()).getRdns().stream()
        .filter(i -> i.getType().equalsIgnoreCase("CN")).findFirst().get().getValue().toString();`

Comment: Note: Although it looks like a fine solution, it has some issues. I was using this one for some years until I discovered decoding issues with "non standard" fields. For fields with types like well known types like `CN` (aka `2.5.4.3`) `Rdn#getValue()` contains a `String`.  However, for custom types, the result is `byte[]` (maybe based on an internal encoded representation starting with `#`). Ofc, `byte[]` -> `String` is possible, but contains additional (unpredictable) characters. I have solved this with @laz solutions based on BC, because it handles and decodes this correctly in `String`.

Answer (score 14):

If adding dependencies isn't a problem you can do this with [Bouncy Castle's](http://www.bouncycastle.org/java.html) API for working with X.509 certificates:

```
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.X509Name;
import org.bouncycastle.jce.PrincipalUtil;
import org.bouncycastle.jce.X509Principal;

...

final X509Principal principal = PrincipalUtil.getSubjectX509Principal(cert);
final Vector<?> values = principal.getValues(X509Name.CN);
final String cn = (String) values.get(0);
```

**Update**

At the time of this posting, this was the way to do this. As gtrak mentions in the comments however, this approach is now deprecated. See gtrak's [updated code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2914521/how-to-extract-cn-from-x509certificate-in-java#5527171) that uses the new Bouncy Castle API.

Comment: it seems like X509Name is deprecated in Bouncycastle 1.46, and they intend to use x500Name.  Know anything about that or the intended alternative to do the same thing?

Comment: Wow, looking at the new API I'm having a hard time figuring out how to accomplish the same goal as the above code. Perhaps the Bouncycastle mailing list archives might have an answer. I'll update this answer if I figure it out.

Comment: I'm having the same problem.  Please let me know if you come up with anything.  This is as far as I've gotten: x500name = X500Name.getInstance(PrincipalUtil.getIssuerX509Principal(cert));
RDN cn = x500name.getRDNs(BCStyle.CN)[0];

Comment: I found how to do it via a mailing list discussion, I created an answer that shows how.

Comment: Good find gtrak. I spent 10 minutes trying to figure it out at one point and never got back around to it.

Comment: I had to get help for that one

Comment: why does it have to be that nasty??

Comment: Have a look at gtrak's answer below. It is using the newer API which is much nicer

Comment: please have a sight at my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40613147/how-to-get-the-policy-identifier-and-the-subject-type-of-basic-constraints-in-a

Answer (score 12):

As an alternative to gtrak's code that does not need ''bcmail'':

```
    X509Certificate cert = ...;
    X500Principal principal = cert.getSubjectX500Principal();

    X500Name x500name = new X500Name( principal.getName() );
    RDN cn = x500name.getRDNs(BCStyle.CN)[0]);

    return IETFUtils.valueToString(cn.getFirst().getValue());
```

@Jakub: I have used your solution until my SW had to be run on Android. And Android does not implement javax.naming.ldap :-(

Comment: That is exactly the same reason I cam up with this solution: porting to Android...

Comment: Not sure when this changed, but this now works: `X500Name x500Name = new X500Name(cert.getSubjectX500Principal().getName());
        String cn = x500Name.getCommonName();` (using java 8)

Comment: please have a sight at my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40613147/how-to-get-the-policy-identifier-and-the-subject-type-of-basic-constraints-in-a

Comment: The `IETFUtils.valueToString` returns the value in **escaped** form. I found simply invoking `.toString()` instead work for me.

Answer (score 11):

All the answers posted so far have some issue: Most use the internal `X500Name` or external Bounty Castle dependency. The following builds on @Jakub's answer and uses only public JDK API, but also extracts the CN as asked for by the OP. It also uses Java 8, which standing in mid-2017, you really should.

```
Stream.of(certificate)
    .map(cert -> cert.getSubjectX500Principal().getName())
    .flatMap(name -> {
        try {
            return new LdapName(name).getRdns().stream()
                    .filter(rdn -> rdn.getType().equalsIgnoreCase("cn"))
                    .map(rdn -> rdn.getValue().toString());
        } catch (InvalidNameException e) {
            log.warn("Failed to get certificate CN.", e);
            return Stream.empty();
        }
    })
    .collect(joining(", "))
```

Comment: In my case the CN is *within* a multi-attribute RDN. I think you'll need to enhance this solution so that for each RDN you would iterate over RDN attributes, rather then just looking at the first attribute of the RDN, which I  think is what you are implicitly doing here.

Answer (score 8):

One line with http://www.cryptacular.org

```
CertUtil.subjectCN(certificate);
```

JavaDoc:
http://www.cryptacular.org/javadocs/org/cryptacular/util/CertUtil.html#subjectCN(java.security.cert.X509Certificate)

Maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.cryptacular</groupId>
    <artifactId>cryptacular</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Note that the Cryptacular 1.1.x series is for Java 7 and 1.2.x for Java 8. Very good library, though!

Answer (score 7):

Here's how to do it using a regex over `cert.getSubjectX500Principal().getName()`, in case you don't want to take a dependency on BouncyCastle.

This regex will parse a distinguished name, giving `name` and `val` a capture groups for each match.

When DN strings contain commas, they are meant to be quoted - this regex correctly handles both quoted and unquotes strings, and also handles escaped quotes in quoted strings:

`(?:^|,\s?)(?:(?<name>[A-Z]+)=(?<val>"(?:[^"]|"")+"|[^,]+))+`

Here is is nicely formatted:

```
(?:^|,\s?)
(?:
    (?<name>[A-Z]+)=
    (?<val>"(?:[^"]|"")+"|[^,]+)
)+
```

Here's a link so you can see it in action:
https://regex101.com/r/zfZX3f/2

If you want a regex to get *only* the CN, then this adapted version will do it:

`(?:^|,\s?)(?:CN=(?<val>"(?:[^"]|"")+"|[^,]+))`

Comment: Most robust answer around. Also, if you want to support even OID's specified by its number (e.g. OID.2.5.4.97), allowed chars should be extended from [A-Z] to [A-Z,0-9,.]

Comment: This seemed to struggle for me with an escaped comma. For example: "O=Acme Stuff\, and more" will parse out as "Acme Stuff\"

Answer (score 6):

Get the common name of the certificate Without using any library. with using regular expression

To get the name

```
String name = x509Certificate.getSubjectDN().getName();
```

to get the extract the common name from the full name

```
    String name = "CN=Go Daddy Root Certificate Authority - G2, O=\"GoDaddy.com, Inc.\", L=Scottsdale, ST=Arizona, C=US";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("CN=(.*?)(?:,|\$)");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(name);
    if (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    }
```

Hope this helps anyone.(-_-)

Comment: Upvoted due to simplicity. However the regex should NOT have the backslash before the dollar sign.

Answer (score 4):

UPDATE: This class is in "sun" package and you should use it with caution. Thanks Emil for the comment :)

Just wanted to share, to get the CN, I do:

```
X500Name.asX500Name(cert.getSubjectX500Principal()).getCommonName();
```

Regarding Emil Lundberg's comment see: [Why Developers Should Not Write Programs That Call 'sun' Packages](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-sun-packages-142232.html)

Comment: This is my favourite among the current answers since it's simple, readable and uses only what's bundled in the JDK.

Comment: Agree with what you said about using JDK classes :)

Comment: One should note, however, that javac warns about `X500Name` being an internal proprietary API that may be removed in future releases.

Comment: Yeah, after reading the [linked FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-sun-packages-142232.html) I need to revoke my first comment. Sorry.

Comment: No problem at all. What you pointed out is really important. Thanks :) In fact, I don't use that class any more :P

Answer (score 3):

I have BouncyCastle 1.49, and the class it has now is org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.Certificate. I looked into the code of `IETFUtils.valueToString()` - it is doing some fancy escaping with backslashes. For a domain name it would not do anything bad, but I feel we can do better. In the cases I've look at `cn.getFirst().getValue()` returns different kinds of strings that all implement ASN1String interface, which is there to provide a getString() method. So, what seems to work for me is

```
Certificate c = ...;
RDN cn = c.getSubject().getRDNs(BCStyle.CN)[0];
return ((ASN1String)cn.getFirst().getValue()).getString();
```

Comment: I ran into the backslash problem, so this fixed my issue.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, thanks to `gtrak` it appears that to get the client certificate and extract the CN, this most likely works.

```
    X509Certificate[] certs = (X509Certificate[]) httpServletRequest
        .getAttribute("javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate");
    X509Certificate cert = certs[0];
    X509CertificateHolder x509CertificateHolder = new X509CertificateHolder(cert.getEncoded());
    X500Name x500Name = x509CertificateHolder.getSubject();
    RDN[] rdns = x500Name.getRDNs(BCStyle.CN);
    RDN rdn = rdns[0];
    String name = IETFUtils.valueToString(rdn.getFirst().getValue());
    return name;
```

Comment: Check this relevant question https://stackoverflow.com/a/28295134/2413303

Answer (score 2):

One more way to do with plain Java :

```java
public static String getCommonName(X509Certificate certificate) {
    String name = certificate.getSubjectX500Principal().getName();
    int start = name.indexOf("CN=");
    int end = name.indexOf(",", start);
    if (end == -1) {
        end = name.length();
    }
    return name.substring(start + 3, end);
}
```

Comment: This is not safe because the CN value could include a comma such as "CN=First\,Last"

Answer (score 1):

Could use cryptacular which is a Java cryptographic library build on top of bouncycastle for easy use.

```
RDNSequence dn = new NameReader(cert).readSubject();
return dn.getValue(StandardAttributeType.CommonName);
```

Comment: Well better use @Erdem Memisyazici suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Fetching CN from certificate is not that simple. The below code will definitely  help you.

```
String certificateURL = "C://XYZ.cer";      //just pass location

CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
X509Certificate testCertificate = (X509Certificate)cf.generateCertificate(new FileInputStream(certificateURL));
String certificateName = X500Name.asX500Name((new X509CertImpl(testCertificate.getEncoded()).getSubjectX500Principal())).getCommonName();
```

Comment: Nope. `X500Name` is a JDK internal class.

Answer (score 1):

BC made the extraction much easier:

```
X500Principal principal = x509Certificate.getSubjectX500Principal();
X500Name x500name = new X500Name(principal.getName());
String cn = x500name.getCommonName();
```

Comment: I can't find any `.getCommonName()` method in [X500Name](http://bouncycastle.org/docs/docs1.5on/org/bouncycastle/asn1/x500/X500Name.html).

Comment: (@lapo) are you sure you aren't actually using `sun.security.x509.X500Name` -- which as other answers noted several years earlier is undocumented and can't be relied on?

Comment: Well, I did link the JavaDoc of `org.bouncycastle.asn1.x500.X500Name` class, which doesn't show that method…

Answer (score 1):

With Spring Security it is possible to use `SubjectDnX509PrincipalExtractor`:

```
X509Certificate certificate = ...;
new SubjectDnX509PrincipalExtractor().extractPrincipal(certificate).toString();
```

Comment: [SubjectDnX509PrincipalExtractor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.6.2/api/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/preauth/x509/SubjectDnX509PrincipalExtractor.html) uses a regular expression under the hood: `"CN=(.*?)(?:,|$)"`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use API 100% dedicated to do this (especially if you have more "advanced" cert) you could use [eu.europa.esig.dss](https://github.com/esig/dss) like so:

```
val x509Certificate = X509CertUtils.parse(certPem)
val certToken = CertificateToken(x509Certificate)

val commonName = DSSASN1Utils.extractAttributeFromX500Principal(
    ASN1ObjectIdentifier(X520Attributes.COMMONNAME.oid),
    X500PrincipalHelper(
        x509Certificate.subjectX500Principal
    )
)
```

The advantage here is that [X520Attributes](https://github.com/esig/dss/blob/master/dss-enumerations/src/main/java/eu/europa/esig/dss/enumerations/X520Attributes.java) class "knows" not only `commonName` but pretty much every possible attribute allowed by spec like `organizationIdentifier`, `encryptedBusinessCategory` and so on (currently 239).

esig.dss lib can also extract cert extensions and many other things. For example PSD2 roles:

```
CertificateExtensionsUtils.getQcStatements(certToken).psd2QcType.rolesOfPSP
```

Answer (score 1):

In java 17 you have a method giving out the names: `getSubjectAlternativeNames` and `getSubjectX500Principal` for the principal name.

The javadoc says it's there since Java 1.4, but I could not find it in the java 8 documentation, so I don't know when it was added.

To get the principal name:

```
System.out.println(cer.getSubjectX500Principal().getName())
```

If there are more than one domain name:

```
System.out.println(cer.getSubjectAlternativeNames().stream().filter(l->l.get(0).equals(2)).map(l -> String.valueOf(l.get(1))).collect(Collectors.joining(",")))
```

Reference: [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/security/cert/X509Certificate.html#getSubjectAlternativeNames())

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [getName(X500Principal.RFC2253, oidMap)](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/security/auth/x500/X500Principal.html#getName(java.lang.String,%20java.util.Map)) or `getName(X500Principal.CANONICAL, oidMap)` to see which one formats the DN string best.  Maybe one of the `oidMap` map values will be the string you want.

Answer (score 0):

Regex expressions, are rather expensive to use. For such a simple task it will probably be an over kill. Instead you could use a simple String split:

```
String dn = ((X509Certificate) certificate).getIssuerDN().getName();
String CN = getValByAttributeTypeFromIssuerDN(dn,"CN=");

private String getValByAttributeTypeFromIssuerDN(String dn, String attributeType)
{
    String[] dnSplits = dn.split(","); 
    for (String dnSplit : dnSplits) 
    {
        if (dnSplit.contains(attributeType)) 
        {
            String[] cnSplits = dnSplit.trim().split("=");
            if(cnSplits[1]!= null)
            {
                return cnSplits[1].trim();
            }
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

Comment: I really like it!
Platform and library independent. This is really cool!

Comment: Down-vote from me. If you read [RFC 2253](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2253#section-3), you'll see there are edge cases you have to consider, e.g. escaped commas `\,` or quoted values.

Answer (score 0):

X500Name is internal implemention of JDK, however you can use reflection.

```
public String getCN(String formatedDN) throws Exception{
    Class<?> x500NameClzz = Class.forName("sun.security.x509.X500Name");
    Constructor<?> constructor = x500NameClzz.getConstructor(String.class);
    Object x500NameInst = constructor.newInstance(formatedDN);
    Method method = x500NameClzz.getMethod("getCommonName", null);
    return (String)method.invoke(x500NameInst, null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For multi-valued attributes - using LDAP API ...

```
        X509Certificate testCertificate = ....

        X500Principal principal = testCertificate.getSubjectX500Principal(); // return subject DN
        String dn = null;
        if (principal != null)
        {
            String value = principal.getName(); // return String representation of DN in RFC 2253
            if (value != null && value.length() > 0)
            {
                dn = value;
            }
        }

        if (dn != null)
        {
            LdapName ldapDN = new LdapName(dn);
            for (Rdn rdn : ldapDN.getRdns())
            {
                Attributes attributes = rdn != null
                    ? rdn.toAttributes()
                    : null;

                Attribute attribute = attributes != null
                    ? attributes.get("CN")
                    : null;
                if (attribute != null)
                {
                    NamingEnumeration<?> values = attribute.getAll();
                    while (values != null && values.hasMoreElements())
                    {
                        Object o = values.next();
                        if (o != null && o instanceof String)
                        {
                            String cnValue = (String) o;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```