# Retrieving subject/CN field from a certificate?

Tags: java, x509certificate, digital-signature, digital-certificate

I want to retrieve a string from the certificate subject field but only its CN value.

to get the whole string I use:

```
Enumeration enumeration = ks.aliases();
while (enumeration.hasMoreElements()) {
    String aliass = (String) enumeration.nextElement();
    X509Certificate cer = (X509Certificate) ks.getCertificate(aliass);
    String s = cer.getSubjectDN().getName().;
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

output is: CN=something, OU=something, DC=something, DC=something, DC=someting

as stated I want to retrieve only the CN string.
is there a short way about it or I should play with substring methods to get the field, also that would not be my preferred way because some certs.getName() are starting with their email address.

Comment: necro-dupe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2914521/how-to-extract-cn-from-x509certificate-in-java and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7933468/parsing-the-cn-out-of-a-certificate-dn

Comment: where does ks object come from?

Answer (score 4):

I think that there is no explicit method to get the `common name` from the certificate using java API (you can get the whole `subjectDN` an parse it to get the `CN`), if you want a method to do so use [`BouncyCastle`](https://www.bouncycastle.org/) classes instead:

```
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x500.X500Name;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x500.style.BCStyle;
import org.bouncycastle.cert.jcajce.JcaX509CertificateHolder;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x500.RDN;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x500.style.IETFUtils;

Enumeration enumeration = ks.aliases();
while (enumeration.hasMoreElements()) {
    String aliass = (String) enumeration.nextElement();
    X509Certificate cer = (X509Certificate) ks.getCertificate(aliass);
    X500Name x500name = new JcaX509CertificateHolder(cert).getSubject();
    RDN cn = x500name.getRDNs(BCStyle.CN)[0];
    String s = IETFUtils.valueToString(cn.getFirst().getValue());
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Hope this helps,

Comment: thanks..will try your code, i have parsed it already. but thanks,def more slicker way of doing it is your way.

Comment: You're welcome, I saw that you have some other questions related to the digital-signature and PKI, probably you've already an answer for them however I'll try to answer a few `:)`.

Comment: yes, I managed to answer almost all of them, but the PKCS11 slot issue is still there, I turned away from it and did it WINDOWS-MY way...but would like to do it the other way also @albciff. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

According to the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/cert/X509Certificate.html) you can try the following:

```
cer.getSubjectX500Principal()
```

Comment: i get a completely the same result with my method and your suggestion.

Comment: so still looking for a solution @funtik

Comment: hmmm... I'm out of ideas :) check if the cert is generated the right way

Comment: I think that the function that you suggested is working just fine, its just that its not its job to pull out CN field from the certs/Subject string