# Java SSL sockets and keytool

Tags: java, sockets, ssl, keystore

I'm working on adding SSL to a client server chat program I have. I'm using a basic socket setup to communicate, but would like to switch over to using SSLsockets so that each session is encrypted, however I'm getting a bit confused with what exactly I need to do with generating, adding, and self signing certificates. I've found a few examples but none were all that helpful.

I know I need to generate a client and server jks file. But am not sure what to do after that. I also need to self sign the certificates.

If anyone could provide a clear breakdown of what all is needed and perhaps some hits or where to find the proper keystore commands to get this done, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Oh come on. The key tool is documented. There is a JSSE Reference Guide.

Comment: See if the end of this answer helps:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22737970/secret-key-ssl-in-java/22738568#22738568