# SSLSocket doesn't perform hostname verification

Tags: java, android, sockets, ssl

I use SSLSocket for my android app
and according to this post  SSLSocket doesn't perform host name verification
[here](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/04/protecting-users-with-tls-by-default-in.html)

and I didn't see any exception while using IP instead of domain and everything works fine 
so can I use IP or any other domain for connection?

I have got the cert from letsencrypt for one domain and I wonder that I can use it for any domain or IP with SSLSocket!

```
SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
sc.init(null, nulls, null);
SocketFactory sslsocketfactory = sc.getSocketFactory();
SSLSocket sslsocket = (SSLSocket) sslsocketfactory.createSocket(host, 443);
sslsocket.setSoTimeout(5000);
sslsocket.startHandshake();
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is on your link:

> Your app **needs to do its own hostname verification**, preferably by calling
>   getDefaultHostnameVerifier() with the expected hostname. Further,
>   beware that HostnameVerifier.verify() **doesn't throw an exception** on
>   error but instead returns a boolean result that you **must explicitly
>   check**.

**"I wonder that I can use it for any domain or IP with SSLSocket!"**

No, you will not be able to do that, the cert of the connection must be in your client's [truststore](https://confluence.atlassian.com/kb/how-to-import-a-public-ssl-certificate-into-a-jvm-867025849.html), and we can expect that the different domains use different certificates :)

Please see this [How should I do hostname validation when using JSSE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18139448/how-should-i-do-hostname-validation-when-using-jsse) link.

Comment: tnx but I am in android studio ! how do that ?