# How to serialize PKCS10CertificationRequest in BouncyCastle to send it over network?

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization, bouncycastle, pem

I have been trying to serialize the object `PKCS10CertificationRequest` for a while now. I figured the right way to do it is to create an `ASN1Primitive` class, send it over the network, then deserialize it. However, there seems to be only *serialization into* ASN1, but there seems to be no *deserialization from* ASN1, and I don't want to manually parse and reconstruct the Request. What should I do? My code so far is

```
    Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
    KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA", "SC");
    kpg.initialize(1024);
    KeyPair kp = kpg.genKeyPair();
    System.out.println("Private: " + kp.getPrivate());
    System.out.println("Public: " + kp.getPublic());

    X500NameBuilder x500NameBld = new X500NameBuilder(BCStyle.INSTANCE);

    x500NameBld.addRDN(BCStyle.C, "AU");
    x500NameBld.addRDN(BCStyle.O, "The Legion of the Bouncy Castle");
    x500NameBld.addRDN(BCStyle.L, "Melbourne");
    x500NameBld.addRDN(BCStyle.ST, "Victoria");
    x500NameBld.addRDN(BCStyle.EmailAddress, "feedback-crypto@bouncycastle.org");

    X500Name subject = x500NameBld.build();

    PKCS10CertificationRequestBuilder requestBuilder = new JcaPKCS10CertificationRequestBuilder(subject, kp.getPublic());

    PKCS10CertificationRequest req1 = requestBuilder.build(new JcaContentSignerBuilder("SHA1withRSA").setProvider("SC").build(
            kp.getPrivate()));

    JcaPKCS10CertificationRequest req2 = new JcaPKCS10CertificationRequest(req1.getEncoded()).setProvider("SC");

//serialization
    ByteArrayOutputStream abOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ASN1OutputStream berOut = new ASN1OutputStream(abOut);
    berOut.writeObject(req2.toASN1Structure());

    byte[] serializedData = abOut.toByteArray();

    ASN1Primitive asn1Primitive = ASN1Primitive.fromByteArray(serializedData);
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("" + asn1Primitive.toString());
```

And the output is

```
[[0, [[[2.5.4.6, AU]], [[2.5.4.10, The Legion of the Bouncy Castle]], [[2.5.4.7, Melbourne]], [[2.5.4.8, Victoria]], [[1.2.840.113549.1.9.1, feedback-crypto@bouncycastle.org]]], [[1.2.840.113549.1.1.1, NULL], #03818D0030818902818100A...
```

I don't want to parse this manually. What should I do instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget about `ASN1`, it is a mess, and there seems to be no automatic deserialization. However, you can use the `JcaPEMWriter` and `PEMParser` classes in BouncyCastle to create a `String` object to serialize or deserialize the data, and send it over the network.

```
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    JcaPEMWriter pemWriter = new JcaPEMWriter(sw);
    pemWriter.writeObject(req2);
    pemWriter.close();

    PEMParser pemParser = null;
    try
    {
       pemParser = new PEMParser(new StringReader(sw.toString()));
       Object parsedObj = pemParser.readObject();
       System.out.println("PemParser returned: " + parsedObj);
       if (parsedObj instanceof PKCS10CertificationRequest)
       {
          JcaPKCS10CertificationRequest jcaPKCS10CertificationRequest = new JcaPKCS10CertificationRequest((PKCS10CertificationRequest)parsedObj);
          System.out.println("" + jcaPKCS10CertificationRequest.getPublicKey());
       }
    }
    catch (IOException ex)
    {
       ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
       if (pemParser != null)
       {
          pemParser.close();
       }
    }
```

EDIT: Although if someone really needs to get elements out of `ASN1Encodable` object (like an `RDN` of `X500Name`, apparently you need the `IETFUtils` class as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/5527171/2413303 .